# Vanilla JS - How to map thu an array of strings, and set InnerHtml of a Button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple app in vanilla JS. I have an array of strings, and I want to map thru the array and assign the values to innerHTML to the buttons. Can I do it with .map()? As of right now, the most I can get is the last thing assigned to the button's innerHTML ('next >')

Here's my code

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
const a = ["click for more", "see more", "details page", "next >"];

a.map((i) => {
  buttons.innerHTML = i;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you think the `s` in `document.getElementsByTagName` signals?

Answer (score 3):

You're so close to the solution. You just need to access the array items with index you get from [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

Note that `Array.map()` is replaced with `Array.forEach()` since you don't use the return value of the `map()` function which creates a new array. (Thanks to @Ivar)

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
const a = ["click for more", "see more", "details page", "next >"];

a.forEach((text, index) => {
  buttons[index].innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to index the button

If you use querySelectorAll on the buttons, you get a [NodeList.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), that makes more sense than the one using the [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const a = ["click for more", "see more", "details page", "next >"];

buttons.forEach((but, i) => {
  but.innerHTML = a[i];
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: For completion - and it's not worth providing yet another answer - it's worth noting that given the `NodeList` of elements and the `Array` of Strings, there's two possibilities: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3cm7ows9/), one with [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), and the other with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: *OP IS looping over the result from the getElements* **No.** They are looping over an array of `string`s. It's exactly the thing marked as a dupe.